# Bash user prompt

Tags: bash

Can someone help please?

I want to run a script that prompts the user to choose one of two options. 
upload or delete.

Whatever option is chosen, the user is then prompted for a name, and subsequently a version. Both of which are captured and inserted into an exec command.
As an example, if I choose "foo" as the name, it then prompts me for a version. And if I choose "0.1.0", then my exec command looks something like this.

```
exec curl -XDELETE http://1.2.3.4/api/charts/foo/0.1.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some recommendations that can improve your chances of receiving an answer; at a minimum it would help if you provided the sample code you've come up with so far, the (incorrect) output it's generating, and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't too hard of a script. I hope this will help.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "UPLOAD or DELETE"

read option

if [ $option == "UPLOAD" ]
then

    # Upload was selected. Now ask for name
    echo "Please Enter A Name: "

    read name

    # Great! Now ask for a version number

    echo "Please Enter A Version: "

    read version

    exec curl -XDELETE http://1.2.3.4/api/charts/$name/$version

elif [ $option == "DELETE" ]
then

    # Delete was selected, do whatever you want here.
    echo "Delete was selected!"

else
    echo "That was not a valid option"
fi
```

The script asks the user for some input, ether (**UPLOAD** or **DELETE**). It then takes that value, if the value is "UPLOAD" then it will continue the script and ask for name and version number. If the user enters "DELETE" then it will echo out "*Delete was selected!*", That is where you can put whatever you want to finish the script. I hope this helps!

Comment: It works like a charm.
Thanks a lot. 

Looking at it, I can see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Note that `exec` isn't needed here, and probably isn't doing what you think it is. `exec` doesn't mean "execute this command", it means "replace the shell executing this script with this command". That is, it immediately exits the shell (and hence script) and executes the command in its place. If you want the script to do anything after running `curl` (like printing a success message, cleaning up temp files, asking if there's another action to do, ...) then do *not* use `exec`. In fact, I'd generally recommend avoiding `exec` even then, simply because it might be a source of confusion later.

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson, thanks a lot. 

And you're right. I noticed that subsequent commands after exec weren't executing and that's what I'm looking to fix now.